# Как сократить и сделать лаконичнее код

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма регистрации на сайте, каждая верно ввседенная операция разблокирует поле для следующего ввода, в одном моменте получисля не оч понятный код, не могу придумать, как его оптимизировать и сделать более читаемым, буду благодарен за помощь

```
confirmPassword.oninput = function(event) {
  event.target.style.color =(event.target.value === password.value)?'#090':'#f00'
    avatar.disabled = button.disabled
      if(button.disabled = !(event.target.value === password.value)){
        button.style['background-color'] = '0f0'
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
confirmPassword.oninput = function ({ target }) {
  avatar.disabled = button.disabled;
  [target.style.color, button.disabled] = (target.value === password.value)
      ? ['#090', false]
      : ['#f00', ((button.style.backgroundColor = '#0f0'), true)]
  // ...
}
```

Может кому-то понравиться вариант из коммента от @Grundy

```js
confirmPassword.oninput = function ({ target }) {
  avatar.disabled = button.disabled;
  [
    target.style.color, 
    button.disabled, 
    button.style.backgroundColor
  ] = (target.value === password.value)
      ? ['#090', false, button.style.backgroundColor]
      : ['#f00', true, '#0f0']
  // ...
}
```

... более читабелен, но использует ненужное САМОприсваивание.

Comment: вообще в вопросе речь шла про _сделать более **читаемым**_ :)

Comment: @Grundy Двум существующим переменным необходимо изменить значения при одном и том же условии `(t.value === p.value)`, при этом изменить `backgroundColor`, когда `!true`(что достигается выражением через запятую). Разумеется, если применять такой стиль крайне редко, либо вообще с ним не сталкиваться - это может показаться странным. Если автору вопроса и это не подходит, он хотя бы может взять себе на заметку.

Comment: Такой стиль в любом случае плохо читаем: тернарный оператор, деструктуризация, присваивание, оператор запятая - и все это в одной строке и с разными переменными :)

Comment: Сделай третьим параметром в деструктуризации `button.style.backgroundColor` и уже будет проще и понятнее

Comment: @Grundy по условию задачи `backgroundColor` изменяется только при  `target.value !== password.value`. Третьим его туда не вставить, т.к. при `target.value === password.value` нужно пройти мимо этого присваивания.

Comment: Вставить же :) просто в случае true - себя же надо передать

Comment: @Grundy ...ты про такой вариант `[,,backgroundColor] = (true|false) ? [,,backgroundColor] : [,,'#0f0']` ???

Comment: да, это самое простое и очевидное решение

Comment: @Grundy добавил, но я привык к выражениям с запятыми, как раз в этих самых тернарных операторах. И мне они больше по душе, без лишних операций.

Answer (score 0):

```
confirmPassword.oninput = ({ target }) => {
  const isError = target.value !== password.value;
  target.style.color = isError ? '#f00': '#090';
  avatar.disabled = isError;
  button.disabled = isError;
  button.style.backgroundColor = isError ? '#0f0' : '';
};
```

Но лучше стили хранить в CSS отдельно, а в JS просто переключать `class`

Comment: `avatar.disabled` должен принимать предыдущее значение `button.disabled`, а у тебя они одинаковые. Посмотри, в if происходит присваивание